# Center form on page both vertically and horizontally

Tags: css, position, media-queries, centering

I would like to center a form on a page and I have managed to do that. I have an issue, though: when I resize the browser windows and the height decreases, I would like the form to stay below the navbar and the page to overflow and allow me to scroll, in order to see the rest of the form. Instead, it positions itself above the navbar.

I have tried to include the form in another container div, tried to used different position values, but I have not succeded to obtain what I want. Is there a simple way?

```css
#navbar {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.test_form {
  /* Center the form on the page vertically */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Center both vertically and horizontally */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  /* Center both vertically and horizontally */
  min-width: 400px;
  width: 28vw;
  max-width: 550px;
  /* Form outline */
  padding: 1em;
  border: 2px solid #192D4D;
  border-radius: 2em;
}

@media only screen and (max-height: 500px) {
  .test_form {
    /* Center the form on the page vertically */
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-width: 400px;
    width: 28vw;
    max-width: 550px;
    /* Form outline */
    padding: 1em;
    border: 2px solid #192D4D;
    border-radius: 2em;
    /* Just to know when it switches */
    background-color: red;
  }
}

label {
  /* Uniform size & alignment */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

input,
textarea {
  /* To make sure that all text fields have the same font settings
     By default, textareas have a monospace font */
  font: 1em sans-serif;
  /* Uniform text field size */
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Match form field borders */
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background-color: #F1F9FF;
}

textarea {
  /* Align multiline text fields with their labels */
  vertical-align: top;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 2px solid #192D4D;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 0, 8rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ADBEDA;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #5C6F8C;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

.submit-button {
  margin-left: calc(1em + 2vw);
  min-width: 100px;
  width: 8vw;
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id='navbar'>

</div>

<br>
<form class="test_form">
  <table border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" scope="row">Table form</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
      <th>asdasd</th>
      <td>asdad</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>asdasd</th>
      <td><input value='asda'></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>asdasd</th>
      <td>asdad</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>asdasd</th>
      <td><textarea>asdads</textarea></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <input class="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The CSS below the `@media` is the code I used before, which only centered the form horizontally, but it had the desired behavior regarding vertical position (stay below navbar and overflow).

https://jsfiddle.net/o4u28qxv/1/

Comment: don't use table for layout. Take a look to [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: static;` and `transform: none;` to the rule for `.test_form` in the media query - this will put the element into the normal flow and reset any offsets caused by `transform`.

https://jsfiddle.net/0ed68aqo/

Answer (score 0):

from html&body, you have a few option to center X/Y your content without  position:

flex possibility

```css
body {
margin:0;
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
height:100vh;
}

div {margin:auto;width:/* if needed*/;}

nav{background:lightgreen}
div {background:lightblue;}
```

```html
<nav> navbar any height</nav>
<div>any content here of any size </div>
```

grid possibility

```css
body {
margin:0;
display:grid;
grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
height:100vh;
}

div {margin:auto;width:/* if needed*/;}

nav{background:lightgreen}
div {background:lightblue;}
```

```html
<nav> navbar any height</nav>
<div>any content here of any size </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use flexbox to center your form instead of using position and transform. It needs less code and in my experience it always worked, on all devices, unless you need support on 8+ years old browsers or internet explorer.

So, for some code, taking what you wrote i edited it like this and it's working for me

```css
#navbar{
  background-color:blue;
  width:100%;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.test_form {
    min-width: 400px;
    width: 28vw;
    max-width: 550px;
    /* Form outline */
    padding: 1em;
    border: 2px solid #192D4D;
    border-radius: 2em;
}

@media only screen and (max-height: 500px) {
.test_form {
    /* Center the form on the page vertically */
    margin: 0 auto;    
    min-width: 400px;
    width: 28vw;
    max-width: 550px;
    /* Form outline */
    padding: 1em;
    border: 2px solid #192D4D;
    border-radius: 2em;
    background-color:red;
    }
}


label {
    /* Uniform size & alignment */
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    text-align: center;
}

input, textarea {
    /* To make sure that all text fields have the same font settings
     By default, textareas have a monospace font */
    font: 1em sans-serif;

    /* Uniform text field size */
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    /* Match form field borders */
    border: 1px solid #999;
    background-color:#F1F9FF;
}

textarea {
    /* Align multiline text fields with their labels */
    vertical-align: top;
}

table {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid #192D4D;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-size: 0,8rem;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#ADBEDA;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #5C6F8C;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

.submit-button {
    margin-left: calc(1em + 2vw);
    min-width:100px;
    width: 8vw;
    max-width:150px;
}

.flex{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
        
}
```

```html
<div id='navbar'>

</div>

<br>
<div class="flex">
  <form class="test_form">
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr><th colspan="2" scope="row">Table form</th></tr>
      </thead>
      <tr><th>asdasd</th><td>asdad</td></tr>
      <tr><th>asdasd</th><td><input value='asda'></td></tr>
      <tr><th>asdasd</th><td>asdad</td></tr>
      <tr><th>asdasd</th><td><textarea>asdads</textarea></td></tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <input class ="submit-button" type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>

</div>
```

In short, i removed from the CSS the position and transform rules in the .test_form class. Wrapped your form inside a  with .flex class and added the flexbox code to the CSS.

`display: flex` makes the div behave like a flexbox container and it's children as flexbox element

`align-items` vertically aligns the content of the div

`justify-content` horizontally aligns the content of the div

Answer (score -2):

Contain `<form>` in `<div>`

```
<div class="container">
    <form class="test_form">
        .............................
    </form>
</div>
```

and I suggest to use only `margin: [value] auto;` to center. remove `position: absolute` and the complentary styles included in achieve a center postition